# How to change JAR build path in Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am building a Java project via Jenkins. The JAR is being created (after I execute maven clean install in Jenkins) in C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.m2\repository\com\other folders.

Is there any way to change this path? I want to sent the JAR to a VM via SSH. However, I am not able to access this folder since this is system directory.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) to copy the created artifact to a particular location...Furthermore for that you don't need `mvn clean install` only `mvn clean package` is needed. ...?

Comment: Another better option would be to deploy your artifact to a repository manager and make separate step in your build pipeline which gets the artifacts and deploys it to the location you need..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, your Jenkins uses this directory as local Maven repository. I would define a different local repository in Jenkins or in the `settings.xml`. It is also important that you make sure that no two running builds use the same local repository at the same time because local repositories cannot be used concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven to build, add the below to your pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <outputDirectory>your custom location</outputDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, maven should create your build artifacts (including the JAR file) in `target` directory next to your `pom.xml`.

You can change this behavior in `pom.xml` by specifying the build directory:

```
<build>
   <directory>/some/other/dir</directory>
</build>
```

The directory you are referring to is your local maven repository, which contains all JAR files maven is working with. You can read more about local maven repository [here](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository).