# How to make Jenkins use the local user's .m2 folder?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jar, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Maven project that needs to use a Maven artifact jar. This jar is there in my C:\Users\username.m2

How do I make Jenkins access this local .m2 folder?

I don't have the dependency-project with me now. So, I cannot build the jar to use it. But, I do have the artifacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already answered your two similar questions today. Please believe me: This is a bad idea.

If you just have the jars and no projects, the best thing you can do is upload them to your company Nexus/Artifactory.

If you don't have one (I would really recommend you to have one - without a Nexus/Artifactory, a Jenkins is not really useful), you can login on the Jenkins machine as the Jenkins user and install these files into the Jenkins local repository. For that, copy the files to that machine and run a command like `mvn install:install-file` with the appropriate parameters (just google maven install plugin). Then they are inside the local repository of Jenkins and you can access them.

Comment: I am already on the machine that has Jenkins and I have logged into Jenkins from the browser. What I am not understanding is - how to add my jars to Jenkins' local .m2? Because, I do not have the maven project for those jars. So, I cannot generate them again.

Comment: As which user is Jenkins running?

Comment: If you installed Jenkins on your own Windows machine, it is probably running a system user. Is that correct?

Comment: Oh, I see. I also answered your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58503940/927493, in which you listed the local repository of Jenkins. You can change that local repository btw if you supply a settings.xml with a different path.

Comment: Is there a way to find a default settings.xml?

Comment: The default settings.xml needs to sit in the folder `.m2` in the user directory (the user directory of the Jenkins user). Your old question tells you where the local repository is, so you will also find the `.m2` directory.

Comment: If there isn't one, just create it.

Comment: Problem is, I cannot find it anywhere. Where does it normally sit? I have looked for it in the Jenkins home directory as well. But, nope, it's not there. I am using Windows.

Comment: Where do I create? That part is not being clear to me, actually. Like, the installation directory? The .jenkins in Users?

Comment: See above what I wrote: "The default settings.xml needs to sit in the folder .m2 in the user directory (the user directory of the Jenkins user). Your old question tells you where the local repository is, so you will also find the .m2 directory."

Comment: The default global location is at ${M2_HOME}/conf and as noted the user settings is in ${HOME}/.m2 . Read @JF-Meier notes and the Maven docs re:[settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html), [installing 3rd party jars](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) and [install:install-file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)